# Can I use Visual Studio 2008 on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-2008

I'm thinking of upgrading to Windows 10 Pro. However, I still have projects that are running in Visual Studio 2008. Due to old third-party library dependencies, I can't convert it to VS 2013 or 2015.

I have searched online, but could not find an answer. Can I run VS 2008 on Windows 10 without a problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Windows 10 supports any application that Windows 7 or Windows 8.x supported.

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: [Can I use Visual Studio 2008,2010 and 2012 on Windows 8?](http://superuser.com/questions/496251/can-i-use-visual-studio-2008-2010-and-2012-on-windows-8), and this one over on SO: [Visual Studio 2008/2010 on Windows 8 - problems?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12543374/visual-studio-2008-2010-on-windows-8-problems)

Comment: Make a full backup before you upgrade, if you run into problems, restore.  Also, you can also revert your Win10 upgrade back to your previous OS for the first 30 days after upgrading (as long as you don't intentionally remove the old version from your HDD before then).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can confirm that Visual Studio 2008 works on Windows 10. I have been running it for a few months now and building large projects with it without any problems.

Comment: The OS does, however, display some warnings concerning the bundled SQL Server 2005, and the VSPerf Profiling Control Driver.

Answer (score 1):

When I tried something similar on my Windows 10 machine, I found that I needed to reinstall all of the Visual C++ Redistributables. After that, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the comment from @Ben Voigt, the "VSPerf Profiling control driver" used by older versions of Visual Studio is not compatible with Windows 10. Therefore to conduct any profiling activities, you either need to run your VS 2008 on Windows 7, or alternatively move to Windows 2012 or higher for Windows 2010.

Source:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/profiler/2012/12/10/the-visual-studio-profiler-on-windows-8/